# Number of records in database between two dates

Tags: .net

I have the following query in .net application

```
SELECT
  COUNT(Counter.DocuID) AS CountDownload,
  Counter.DocuID,
  CONVERT(CHAR(4), Counter.DownloadDate, 112),
  Table.DocName
FROM Counter
INNER JOIN Table ON Counter.DocuID = Table.DocID
WHERE (Counter.DocuID = @DocID)
  AND (Counter.DownloadDate >= @startDate)
  AND (Counter.DownloadDate < DATEADD(DAY, 1, @endDate))
  AND (Table.DocType <> @DocType)
GROUP BY
  Counter.DocuID,
  CONVERT(CHAR(4), Counter.DownloadDate, 112),
  Table.DocName,
  Table.DocType
```

I need this query to provide the following output

> DocID: 1
> DocName : NameofDoc
> CountofDownloads : 123

In which CountofDownloads is total number of rows between start and end dates.

Instead I get CountofDownloads split by year if date range is in two different years:

> DocID: 1 
> DocName : NameofDoc 
> CountofDownloads : 100

> DocID: 1 
> DocName : NameofDoc 
> CountofDownloads : 23

Can I get a grand total without splitting by year?

Answer (score 1):

Wrap your query in a group by:

```
select
  DocID,
  DocName,
  sum(CountofDownloads) as CountofDownloads
from (
    -- your query here
) x
group by DocID, DocName
```

Comment: The "group by" line should be "group by DocID". Realistically,  it shouldn't make any difference if the same DocName is always used with a DocID as should be the case.

Comment: @DamilolaAdegunwa you must list all non-aggregating selected columns in the group by, even if it "doesn't make sense". Actually, the entire group by clause doesn't make sense, because it adds no value: It is entirely predetermined by "all non-aggregating selected columns" - it should be removed from the language.